# TryFrom trait for composed tuples

Tags: rust, type-conversion, tuples

Here's a working solution for part of the rustlings `try_from` exercise.

```rust
impl TryFrom<(i16, i16, i16)> for Color {
    type Error = IntoColorError;
    fn try_from(tuple: (i16, i16, i16)) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        let (red, green, blue) = tuple;
        match (u8::try_from(red), u8::try_from(green), u8::try_from(blue)) {
            (Ok(red), Ok(green), Ok(blue)) => Ok(Color { red, green, blue }),
            _ => Err(Self::Error::IntConversion),
        }
    }
}
```

This is a fine solution but there is a lot of repitition of code. It seemed sensible to have a solution where the tuple conversion can be done in a single expression. Something like:

```rust
impl TryFrom<(i16, i16, i16)> for Color {
    type Error = IntoColorError;
    fn try_from(tuple: (i16, i16, i16)) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        match <(u8, u8, u8)>::try_from(tuple) {
            Ok((red, green, blue)) => Ok(Color { red, green, blue }),
            _ => Err(Self::Error::IntConversion),
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't work, but it seems reasonable that the compiler could automatically infer the `TryFrom` trait for composed tuples. Is there some way to get this behaviour?

Comment: Consider implementing it for an array instead. Then you can easily shorten it.

Answer (score 3):

I think on current stable what you have is perfectly fine. On Nightly, or once the `try_map()` method on arrays gets stabilized, you have access to a much nicer implementation, though:

```
#![feature(array_try_map)]

impl TryFrom<(i16, i16, i16)> for Color {
    type Error = IntoColorError;
    fn try_from(tuple: (i16, i16, i16)) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        let [red, green, blue] = <[_; 3]>::from(tuple).try_map(u8::try_from)?;
        Ok(Color { red, green, blue })
    }
}
```

This makes use of `impl From<(T, T, T)> for [T; 3]`, which was stabilised in Rust version 1.71, as well as the `try_map()` method mentioned above, which is still unstable.

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d7d589f8c724bd9e536170c29f442da8))

If you want to add further `From` and `TryFrom` implementations for `Color`, you can build them on top of each other and reduce the code in each impl to a minimum, e.g.:

```
impl TryFrom<(i16, i16, i16)> for Color {
    type Error = IntoColorError;
    fn try_from(rgb: (i16, i16, i16)) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        <[_; 3]>::from(rgb).try_into()
    }
}
impl TryFrom<[i16; 3]> for Color {
    type Error = IntoColorError;
    fn try_from(rgb: [i16; 3]) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        Ok(rgb.try_map(u8::try_from)?.into())
    }
}
impl From<[u8; 3]> for Color {
    fn from([red, green, blue]: [u8; 3]) -> Self {
        Color { red, green, blue }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would this need `IntoColorError: From<TryFromIntError>`?

Comment: @BallpointBen Yes, it does – see the playground code linked in the post. It makes sense to have that conversion anyway, and you could use a library like `thiserror` to reduce the boilerplate. Alternatively, you could add `.map_error(...)` after `try_map()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the tuple into an array so that you can use `map`:

```rust
impl TryFrom<(i16, i16, i16)> for Color {
    type Error = String;
    fn try_from(tuple: (i16, i16, i16)) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        let (red, green, blue) = tuple;
        let colors = [red, green, blue].map(u8::try_from);
        match colors {
            [Ok(red), Ok(green), Ok(blue)] => Ok(Color { red, green, blue }),
            _ => Err(Self::Error::IntConversion),
        }
    }
}
```

But it's probably cleaner to just implement it for an array from the start.

```rust
impl TryFrom<[i16; 3]> for Color {
    type Error = String;
    fn try_from(arr: [i16; 3]) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        let colors = arr.map(u8::try_from);
        match colors {
            [Ok(red), Ok(green), Ok(blue)] => Ok(Color { red, green, blue }),
            _ => Err(Self::Error::IntConversion),
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution that doesn't avoid repetition, but IMHO it's a bit more clean to read is using the `let ... = ... else {...}`. Since we're only matching one specific pattern we don't need to use the `match` syntax.

```
// Tuple implementation
impl TryFrom<(i16, i16, i16)> for Color {
    type Error = IntoColorError;
    fn try_from(tuple: (i16, i16, i16)) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        let (Ok(r), Ok(g), Ok(b)) = (
            u8::try_from(tuple.0),
            u8::try_from(tuple.1),
            u8::try_from(tuple.2),
        ) else {
            return Err(IntoColorError::IntConversion);
        };
        Ok(Color {
            red: r,
            green: g,
            blue: b,
        })
    }
}
```